# How can I pass results from one query into a second query and display the results in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I am using Codeigniter and am trying to pass the results of one query into a second. I receive the error

> "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
For my $truck_num query I am simply grabbing a list of trucks in a field called truck_num. I am then trying to pass those results into a query that does some calculations.

Controller
///////////

```
    function average_battery_life_by_truck() {

    $truck_num = $this->mhedash_model->select_truck();

    foreach($truck_num->result_array() as $row) {
    $array = $row['truck_num']; 
    $results[] = $this->mhedash_model->select_battery_life_truck($array);

    }

    $data['array'] = $results;

    $data['main_content'] = 'mhe/average_truck_bat';
    return $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);



}
```

View
//////

```
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>

<p><h1></h1></p>


<FORM 
<></div>
<br />
<p><h4 id="date"></h4></p>
<h3></h3>
<table id="table" class="sortable">
<THEAD>
    <TR>
        <TH>Truck</TH>
        <TH>Average Hours</TH>

    </TR>
</THEAD>

<TBODY>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($array as $row): ?>

    <TR >
        <TD><?php echo $row['average_bat_life']; ?></TD>
        <TD><?php echo $row['truck_num']; ?></TD>

    </TR>
    <?php $count++; ?>

<?php endforeach;?>
</TBODY>

</table>
```

MODEL/////

```
    function select_truck() {
    mysql_select_db('battery');
    $this->table_name = 'truck';


    $truck_num = "SELECT 
                    truck_num
                  FROM 
                    truck
                  WHERE 
                    battery_type_id = '5'
                    or battery_type_id = '8'
                    or battery_type_id = '10'
                    or battery_type_id = '9'
                  ORDER BY truck_num
              ";

             return $this->db->query($truck_num);
}

function select_battery_life_truck($data) {
    mysql_select_db('battery');
    $this->table_name = 'truck_hours';
    $truck_num = $this->db->escape($data);


    /*This query takes the current row's metered hours and subtracts it with the previous row's metered hours.
    We then average out the time the battery was on the truck for the date range */


    $query = "SELECT 
                ROUND(AVG(metered_hours-b),2) average_bat_life,
                truck_num
              FROM   (SELECT
                        id,
                        metered_hours,
                        loc_id,
                            (SELECT MAX(metered_hours) 
                             FROM 
                                (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 id, truck_hours.metered_hours,truck_hours.loc_id from truck_hours,truck, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r where truck_hours.loc_id = truck.loc_id and truck.truck_num = $truck_num and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= truck_hours.ctrl_date  ) a 
                                 WHERE a.metered_hours < t.metered_hours)b

                                 FROM 
                            (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 id, truck_hours.metered_hours,truck_hours.loc_id from truck_hours,truck, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r where truck_hours.loc_id = truck.loc_id and truck.truck_num = $truck_num and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= truck_hours.ctrl_date ) AS t) c,
                            truck

              WHERE c.loc_id = truck.loc_id 
              ORDER BY average_bat_life";
    return $this->db->query($query);
}
```

Comment: Where is your model file???

Comment: I just added it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: In your view you use `foreach($array->result_array() as $row) {`

Comment: hm no dice, it returns Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object on line 24 of my view which is the foreach line.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that I just removed the brackets [ ] from my $results in my controller and it gave me a table of empty rows and no errors. I can see that the mysql data ran but didn't display on the page. I did this after testing the result_array in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second  query you are not fetching data from database.

So you need to add fetch method

In your controller

```
foreach($truck_num->result_array() as $row) {
    $array = $row['truck_num']; 
    $result = $this->mhedash_model->select_battery_life_truck($array);
    foreach($result->result_array() as $row_data) {
         $results[] = $row_data; 
    }
    }
      $data['array'] = $results;
      $data['main_content'] = 'mhe/average_truck_bat';
      $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
```

Comment: I think this is very close to being complete. With your new code it runs the query and returns 116 rows in a table as expected. The table fields are all blank but this is a huge step.

Comment: Glad to know it will help you to remove your error!!

Comment: It's working now. I made my $row['truck_num'] uppercase on the controller and the view, did the same for the $row['average_bat_life'] too. You're awesome.